Unable to use flash attention to train llama model
I am performing a training run and use Flash attention 2 with the llama model.
Unfortunately, I hit this error
 LlavaLlamaForCausalLM.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attn_implementation'

I have followed advice from here https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/issues/1103
and still get the error  on 4.38.0,
Here is how i set it up.
model = LlamaForCausalLM( config = hparams.model_config, attn_implementation="flash_attention_2" )

I would appreciate any pointers
